# Linq to entities : Many to many in one single select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this domain:

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Application
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserApplications
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Application")]
    public long ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public Application Application { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastConnection { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make a select that returns something like that:

```
List of select new
{
    User = user,
    Applications = applications // List of all user's applications
}
```

I try:

```
from u in Users
join ua in UserApplications on u.Id equals ua.UserId into userApplications
from ua in userApplications.DefaultIfEmpty()
join a in Applications on ua.ApplicationId equals a.Id into applications
select new
{
    User = u,
    Applications = applications
}
```

But this repeats the user to each application.

I know that I can do that in two select statements, but I dont want that.

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not remember if Entity Frameworks could do `groupby` based on the entity object itself (and extract it's `Id` behind the scene and replace things as it fits and the like); but this code works for this case:

```
var q = from uapp in cntxt.UserApplications
        group uapp by uapp.UserId
            into g
            select new { UserId = g.Key, Applications = g.Select(x => x.Application) };
```

And if you are willing to have `User` already extracted:

```
var q2 = from uapp in cntxt.UserApplications
            group uapp by uapp.UserId
                into g
                let u = Users.First(x => x.Id == g.Key)
                select new { User = u, Applications = g.Select(x => x.Application) };
```

Assuming you are writing a query against an Entity Framework Context - and not just trying to do a Linq to Objects query.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but Applications must be a List<Application>, not List<UserApplication>.

Comment: It just needed extracting `Application` property from items of `g`! :)

Comment: And it's better to not mix up Linq to Object (extension) method calls like `ToList` with your Linq to Entity queries. Instead iterate over your Linq to Entity query and transform your model to (say) View Model objects instead (And it would be perfect if you go through some more coding and extract them from database in a lazy manner, instead of pulling all of them into memory; you'll see the difference in tasks like paging, in which case, there is no actual need for whole set of answers).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var tmp =
    from u in Users
        join ua in UserApplications on u.Id equals ua.UserId
        join a in Applications on ua.ApplicationId equals a.Id
    select new
        {
            User = u,
            App = a
        };
var res = tmp
    .ToArray() // edited
    .GroupBy(_ => _.User)
    .Select(_ => new 
        {
            User = _.Key, 
            Applications = _.Select(_ => _.App).ToArray()
        });
```

Comment: I'm afraid, this will fail, because `tmp` still is `IQueryable<T>`, hence `ToArray` can't be translated to SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you just have to group `UserApplications` entity set by user:

```
context
    .UserApplications
    .GroupBy(_ => _.User, _ => _.Application)
    .ToList();
```

because, in fact, `IGrouping<User, Application>` is what you need (`Key` is the user, and group items are his applications).

Any other improvements are matter of taste, like projection to anonymous type:

```
context
    .UserApplications
    .GroupBy(_ => _.User, _ => _.Application)
    .Select(_ => new
    {
        User = _.Key,
        // since IGrouping<User, Application> is IEnumerable<Application>,
        // we colud return a grouping directly
        Applications = _  
    })
    .ToList();
```

(another projection option throws away group key in `Applications`):

```
context
    .UserApplications
    .GroupBy(_ => _.User, _ => _.Application)
    .Select(_ => new
    {
        User = _.Key,
        Applications = _.Select(app => app)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Dennis! Is possible to do that just with linq to entitites?  I mean, wity "from", "group" and "select" clauses?

Comment: This *is* LINQ to entities, just another form - method syntax (while your sample uses query syntax).